# MKMapView: Get clicked event on annotation pin

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, mkmapview

I am using an `MKMapView` containing a couple of `MKAnnotation` pins.
Above the map I am showing a `UITableView` with detailed information of the `MKAnnotation` pins.

My problem: When I select a pin, I would like to select the corresponding table cell.
For this I would like to catch an event/delegate if the pin is selected. I am not talking about calling the callout accessory

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Answer (score 42):

Just an update to this -- in iOS 4 there are MKMapViewDelegate methods that can be used to track annotation selection and de-selection:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

Comment: If you want to know if the user is clicking on an expanded/selected annotation you can check view.selected == YES in didSelectAnnotationView

Answer (score 3):

you can use an Observer for Selected-Event:

```
[pin addObserver:self
      forKeyPath:@"selected" 
         options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
         context:@"ANSELECTED"];
```

---

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{

    NSString *action = (NSString*)context;

    if([action isEqualToString:@"ANSELECTED"]){

        BOOL annotationAppeared = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];
        if (annotationAppeared) {
            // clicked on an Annotation
        }
        else {
            // Annotation disselected
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a simple way to do this in MapKit. There's no `mapView:annotationWasTapped:` on the delegate.

One way to do it would be to provide your own annotation view subclass. The custom annotation view could capture the pin selection in `setSelected:animated:` or in a lower level event handler and pass that information up to your view controller.

Comment: This is the way I was doing it as well. Strange that Apple didn't provide any callback for that :/