# iPhone: MKAnnotation Pin Color "Selected-State"

Tags: iphone, ios, mkpinannotationview

Can anyone tell me how to change the "selected state" of a annotation pin color. Meaning if you have a group of 10 pins and they are red and if you select a pin it changes to purple.

Answer (score 0):

You have to "catch" the select action on the MKAnnotation view. And then change the color on it.
Catching the event is described here : [MKMapView: Get clicked event on annotation pin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599406/mkmapview-get-clicked-event-on-annotation-pin/1603624#1603624)